# Speed up video and audio for multiple strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I want to speed up my complete video (all strips combined) 15 times.

My timeline looks like this:

[image]

If I make a meta strip out of the video and audio separately, add an effect strip -> speed control, I can work with the video, but the audio keeps playing in normal speed. How do I speed up my whole video 15 times?

Comment: Iirc, there is no way to speed up audio inside Blender. Not even by changing the frame rate of the project.

Comment: Are you sure @tintwotin? This guy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qm7Bl_gO0JI) managed to speed up the audio by increasing the pitch. This indeed works, but just for single strips. For my combined strips, it does not have the effect. If I make a meta strip out of the strip sequence, the pitch option disappears :( So, what is the way to go for speed up a whole video + audio in Blender?

Comment: Ah, great. I did not know that. If you select all of your audio strips, change the pitch value of the active strip(white outline), right click on the pitch value and select Copy to Selected or +Alt while changing the value, then the value will be applied to all selected strips. 
As neither Adjustment Layer strips, Scene strips nor Meta strips have audio options, there doesn't seems to be the exact solution available you're asking for.

Comment: I guess the simplest way to solve this is to make a lossless(raw) export of the whole thing, import in in a fresh project, add the 15 times speed and the 15 times pitch to the audio.